# Bug?: Action type: 'watch' must be submitted for approval

Tags: facebook, configuration, facebook-opengraph

Is this a bug?

When I click 'Create New Action Type' on the Open Graph dashboard and choose 'watch' or 'like' or 'read' I get this on top of the configuration page:

> Approval Status: Unsubmitted This Action Type must be submitted for
>   approval in order for it be visible to all users.

Strange no? I thought yesterday these common actions worked just fine. What changed is that a added an action type for approval.

Is it normal I see this message when I choose 'watch' or something common?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to submit every action to be reviewed whether it's a stock or a custom one. This will ensure that your application meets the requirements set by the Open Graph Checklist:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/checklist/